# How to work with 20 m spatial resolution bands in Sentinel-2 Imagery Level2A GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-2

I am using the following script to make a query of Sentinel-2 Imagery Level-2 with GEE code editor.

```
// ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
// Finding images in the Sentinel2 L2A Collection 
// ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
var s2_2018_03_01TO2018_05_31 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR")
  .filterMetadata('MGRS_TILE', 'equals', '32UQC')
  .filterDate('2018-03-01', '2018-05-31')
  .filter(ee.Filter.lte('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 30));

print(s2_2018_03_01TO2018_05_31)
```

[image]

I attached an image showing the bands found in every image element of my image collection. I used SNAP in the pass to process the Level-1C Sentinel-2 Imagery to Level-2A. I can select which resolution I would like to work with. In my project I would like to use 20m spatial resolution imagery. Question, is there a way to have all bands in this resolution, instead that having elements with different spatial resolution in my image collection? Is there a method to scale down the bands B02, B03, B04 and B08 to 20m spatial resolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably ignore the scale while doing your processing, and set it to 20m when you export your final results. You can read up on the details on how scale works in EE in the docs: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/scale#image-pyramids

```
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: image, 
  description: 'my_filename', 
  scale: 20, 
  crs: 'EPSG:4326', 
  maxPixels: 1e12
})
```